# A (1950s?) book about a later solution inventor (possibly a Henry Kuttner collection)

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, books

I've hunted for years and have still yet to recapture the author's name or title of this short story collection. I am trying to recall the details as best as my memory - forty-plus years later - tries to bring them back.

It is a collection of a dozen or two SF stories from somewhere in the 1930s to 1950s probably; it was in a tattered paperback in my local small town library in the mid-1970s. (In Canada, so it could have been British SF, but likely American.)

All the stories were about a scientist / inventor who was slightly bent. He would be called on to come up with something and the solution he came up with would fit the request made of him, but it would ironically undermine the original request, similar to the resolutions of Isaac Asimov's Azazel stories. For example, and this is the short story I remember most clearly, the military has come to the scientist / inventor to create an army to replace human soldiers. He does this by creating an army of human-sized rabbit-like clones/creatures, but the twist of the story is that all the rabbits are female and therefore unable to be drafted and serve as soldiers. Six- or seven-year-old me just laughed and laughed at this. The rest of the collection is like that, but this was the one I laughed at, small, naive child that I was.

Over the years when I've described this story and this story collection, people have pointed me to Frederic Brown and Henry Kuttner, but I've read through their books and, for the life of me, I can't find this story among them.
This strike any bells with anyone?

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/155618.The_Incredible_Adventures_of_Professor_Branestawm might be a good match. I'll see if I can find a copy to verify the rabbit soldiers story.

Comment: I'd love to read this. As a child I loved the Professor Branestawm books that FuzzyBoots mentions and this sounds similar (though it's not a Branestawm book). I have a pretty complete collection of Henry Kuttner's works and there is nothing in them that matches your description. I'm not as familiar with Fredric Brown's work but nothing I've read of his matches.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I think Branestawm might be it, but it looks like there are several books in the series.

Comment: Just a side note: The people who refer you to Harry Kuttner are probably remembering his set of stories about an inventor named "Gallagher." But I agree that his adventures are not actually what you are describing. His inventions tended to work *extremely well* for solving the specified problem, whatever it was. (First story I ever read about him had him waking up from a bender, looking at something very weird in his lab, and muttering: "I must have built that while I was in a drunken creative trance -- I wonder what it does?" Only at the end of the story had he figured it all out.)

Comment: If it is the Branestawn books, you might be interested to know the BBC adapted some of them for television a few years ago. https://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b04w7pd3

Comment: That reminds me of the Papa Schimmelhorn stories of a dirty old man who is a sub-conscious genius. Very objectifying of women but he does get payback from his long-suffering wife when she catches up with him. The author for those is Reginald Bretnor: https://www.goodreads.com/series/290462-papa-schimmelhorn

Answer (score 3):

I'm starting to suspect this isn't the correct answer, but this could be one of Norman Hunter's *[Professor Branestawm](https://childrensbooks.fandom.com/wiki/Professor_Branestawm)* books.

> The Professor was a great (if absent-minded) inventor, always ready to turn his genius to the practical affairs of housekeeping, whether in the matter of a burglar trap of some comprehensive device to get spring-cleaning over quickly. His best intentions, however, seemed to land him in the worst scrapes. Sometimes they involved his housekeeper, Mrs. Flittersnoop, sometimes his best friend Colonel Dedshott, but somehow he never managed to solve the comparatively simple problem of keeping count of the five pairs of spectacles which he generally wore simultaneously so as to be prepared for all eventualities.

As you can see by the description, it does involve a friend in the military (part of the Catapult Cavaliers who only use the eponymous weapon) and the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Professor_Branestawm) mentions more military members that he invents for including General Shatterfortz and Commander Hardaport.

The Internet Archive has a copy of the first book, *[The Incredible Adventures of Professor Branestawm](https://archive.org/details/incredibleadvent0000hunt/)*, available for loan, but none of the stories I scanned matches up with your description, although there were at least four more books that would fit your timeframe.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I think Branestawm might be it, but it looks like there are several books in the series.